# How to prove linearly independence of functions by induction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, induction

I have the following functions $$e^{a_1x}, e^{a_2x}, e^{a_3x}$$

I want to prove that they are linearly independent, if $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are pairwise disjoin constants. The problem is solvable by direct application of the Wronskian, but it is written that there is a way (which I cannot find) to solve it by induction.

Comment: no you can not use induction you must consider an equation system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose there is a relation $k_1e^{a_1x}+\cdots + k_re^{a_rx}=0,$ where the sequence of $a_k$ are arranged in increasing order, and all $k_i \neq 0.$

Now divide through by $e^{a_r x}$ and let $x \to \infty.$ This will produce $0=k_r,$ contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution. I want just to ask, why should we set all $k_i \neq 0$?

Comment: If any are zero just drop those terms and get a shorter relation.

Answer (score 5):

The following proof by induction works for either real or complex scalars.

Theorem: If $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ are distinct scalars, then the functions $\exp(a_i x)$ are linearly independent.

The case $n=1$ is obvious.  Suppose it is true for $n$, and consider
$\exp(a_j x)$ for $j = 1 \ldots n+1$.

If some linear combination $$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} k_j e^{a_j x} = 0$$ for scalars $k_j$, then also
$$ \sum_j k_j e^{(a_j - a_i) x}  = 0$$
and taking the derivative of this,
$$ \sum_j k_j (a_j - a_i) e^{(a_j - a_i) x} = 0 $$
But the coefficient for $j=i$ is $0$, so this is a linear combination of the $n$ functions $\exp(a_j x)$ for $j\ne i$.  By the induction hypothesis,
all $k_j$ for $j \ne i$ are $0$.  That leaves your linear combination as
$k_i e^{a_i x} = 0$, so by the case $n=1$, $k_i = 0$ as well.

Comment: This proof doesn't rely on order properties (as expected since the complexes aren't ordered). +1.

Comment: This is the usual proof that eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues of an endomorphism (in this case the derivative on $C^\infty(\mathbb R)$) are linearly independent.