# Prove linear independence using mathematical induction

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, induction

Given the following set of functions:
$1,\sin(x),\sin(2x),\sin(3x), \cdots, \sin(nx)$ (n is integer, n>0)
The thing to be done is to prove that the set of functions is linearly independent using mathematical induction.
I googled for common tasks, now it is clear that mathematical induction will work fine, but I have no idea of how to do it.
How to apply the method here?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275023/how-to-prove-linearly-independence-of-functions-by-induction

Comment: Does it have to be proven via induction, or will other methods suffice here?

Comment: How can you be sure induction will work, if you have no idea how?

Comment: In the original task it was mentioned to do it with induction

Comment: Usually, it's not done that way, that's why most aren't eager to answer (and @Dave asked if other methods are sufficient).

Answer (score 3):

In mathematics, you start with the definition: linear independence of those funcions means that whenever $\displaystyle a_0+\sum^n_{k=1}a_k\sin kx=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $a_k=0$ for $k=0,\ldots,n$. Now that's trivial for $n=0$ (where you have only $a_0$, the sum is empty): you just let $x=0$ and get $a_0=0$. Now let's assume it's true for $n$ summands, and let's consider $n+1$:
$$f(x)=a_0+\sum^{n+1}_{k=1}a_k\sin kx=0$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then,
$$0=\frac12\left[f\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)}\right)+f\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)}\right)\right]=a_0+\sum^{n+1}_{k=1}a_k\cos\frac{k\pi}{2(n+1)}\sin kx,$$ using the well-known identity $$\sin(u+v)+\sin(u-v)=2\sin u\cos v.$$ But the last summand with $k=n+1$ is $0$, because $$\cos\frac{(n+1)\pi}{2(n+1)}=\cos\frac{\pi}2=0,$$ so we have
$$a_0+\sum^n_{k=1}a_k\cos\frac{k\pi}{2(n+1)}\sin kx=0$$ a sum only including $n$ summands, so we know that $a_0=0$ and $\displaystyle a_k\cos\frac{k\pi}{2(n+1)}=0$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$. Since $\displaystyle\cos\frac{k\pi}{2(n+1)}\neq0$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$, this means $a_k=0$. Then, we are left with $$f(x)=a_{n+1}\sin(n+1)x=0$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, so $a_{n+1}=0$, too.

Comment: Can you explain the step where you have written $\dfrac{1}{2} \left[ f \left( x + \dfrac{\pi}{2 \left( n + 1 \right)} \right) + f \left( x - \dfrac{\pi}{2 \left( n + 1 \right)} \right) \right] = 0$?